# How to perform image arithmetic for distinct size images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to perform simple arithmetic operations like sum, difference, division, and, etc to images.

An example of what I'm doing is:

```
function I = difference_matlab(source1, source2)
image1 = rgb2gray(imread(source1));
image2 = rgb2gray(imread(source2));
I = mat2gray(image1 - image2);

subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(image1)
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(image2)
subplot(2,2,3:4)
imshow(I);

end
```

However this will fail when images are not same size, **how can I overlap images so operations are performed in common area?** That's something like *take smaller image and mount it over bigger, cropping operations region*. However I can't figure out how to do it with out looping each image matrix.

Comment: If the images are in different size, how do you define "common area"?

Comment: Smaller over bigger and *common area behind* it's what I want

Comment: With which offset? The small image can be put on top of the big one in many different ways.

Comment: `(0,0)` of smaller at `(0,0)` of bigger

Comment: The size of result image is the bigger one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To crop both images to the size of the smaller one (or also to the smallest size in X, Y and Z direction):

```
function I = difference_matlab(source1, source2)
image1 = rgb2gray(imread(source1));
image2 = rgb2gray(imread(source2));

minsize=min([size(image1); size(image2)], [], 1);

image1=image1(1:minsize(1), 1:minsize(2), 1:minsize(3));
image2=image2(1:minsize(1), 1:minsize(2), 1:minsize(3));

I = mat2gray(image1 - image2);

subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(image1)
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(image2)
subplot(2,2,3:4)
imshow(I);

end
```

To pad the smaller one with zeros:

```
function I = difference_matlab(source1, source2)
image1 = rgb2gray(imread(source1));
image2 = rgb2gray(imread(source2));

maxsize=max([size(image1); size(image2)], [], 1);

image1_padded=zeros(maxsize);
image2_padded=zeros(maxsize);

image1_padded(1:size(image1, 1), 1:size(image1, 2), 1:size(image1, 3))=image1;
image2_padded(1:size(image2, 1), 1:size(image2, 2), 1:size(image2, 3))=image2;

I = mat2gray(image1_padded - image2_padded);

subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(image1)
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(image2)
subplot(2,2,3:4)
imshow(I);

end
```

No idea if there is a more elegant solution for the zero padding, but I think it should do the trick!

pick what you like more :-)